# mongoose.js make update methods stop returning documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I wonder if it is possible to not return any data from database after using the `SOME_MODEL.findOneAndUpdate()` function.

I can of course use `lean()` and `select()`
.
I just need a callback with information about the completed update to `response.sendStatus(200`) to client.

Do the documents returned unnecessarily from database waste network transfer etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [Model.updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne)

> Each model has its own update method for modifying documents in the database without returning them to your application.